# Finding the points of discontinuity of $f(x)= [x]\sin\left(\frac{π}{[x+1]}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Let

$$f(x)= [x]\sin\left(\frac{π}{[x+1]}\right)$$

where $[x]$ represents the greatest integer function/ floor function.

I need to find the points of discontinuity of this function in it's domain , which is $\mathbb R-[-1,0)$.

It is continuous at all non-integer points and zero. For any other integer $I(I≠-1,0)$, I get the following left hand limits $(LHL)$ and right hand limits $(RHL)$ :

$$LHL= (I-1)\sin\left(\frac{π}{I}\right)$$

$$RHL= (I)\sin\left(\frac{π}{I+1}\right)$$

If it's continuous at $I$ ,  then , $$ (I-1)\sin\left(\frac{π}{I}\right)= (I)\sin\left(\frac{π}{I+1}\right)$$

However, I don't know if any integer satisfy this equation. How can I proceed to prove/disprove that this equation has no other integral solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A possibile path**

Let
$$g(x) = x\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x+1}\right).$$
You get
$$g'(x) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x+1}\right)-\frac{\pi x}{(x+1)^2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x+1}\right).\tag{1}\label{1}$$
Now, for positive integers, you can use the fact that, for $t>0$,$$\sin t > t-\frac{t^3}6,$$
and that, for $0<t<\frac{\pi}2$,$$\cos t <1,$$
to write
$$g'(x)> \frac{\pi}{x+1}-\frac{\pi^3}{6(x+1)^3}-\frac{\pi x}{(x+1)^2}.$$
So, for $x>-1$ we have that $g'(x)$ is certainly positive if
$$1-\frac{\pi^2}{6(x+1)^2}-\frac{x}{x+1}>0$$
which is satisfied for $$x > \frac{\pi^2}6-1.$$
Thus **for every positive integer** $n$, $$g'(n)>0$$ hence $$g(n+1)>g(n).$$ So there are no positive integer solutions to your equation.

As for negative integers, use the fact that for $t<0$
$$\sin t > t,$$ and $$\cos t > 1-\frac{t^2}2$$to obtain, from \eqref{1}
$$g'(x) > \frac{\pi}{x+1}-\frac{\pi x}{(x+1)^2}\left[1-\frac{\pi^2}{2(x+1)^2}\right].$$ The above quantity, for $x\neq -1$, is positive when
$$2x^2+(4+\pi^2)x+2>0.$$In the range of our interest, we get
$$x < -1-\frac{\pi^2}{4}-\frac{\pi\sqrt{\pi^2+8}}4.$$So there are **no negative solutions to your problem for $$n<-7.$$** You can check manually the remaining range.

Comment: Quite lengthy but thanks for the approach.

Comment: @An_Elephant I am sure, too, there must be some shorter way.